# Boot xubuntu from network

Tags: boot, networking, xubuntu, pxe, syslinux

I am trying to make Xubuntu available to pxe boot.
I used dnsmasq and configured it to boot ubuntu net install. It worked well. But since I did not find Xubuntu's net install version, I configured the pxe server to boot the regular Xubuntu image (18.04.1 here).
The Linux kernel and the initrd are downloaded by the client but at some point during the startup process (before lightdm) a message is displayed every second saying that /dev/sr0 is unreachable.
I guess the system is configured to look for its files at this place and it does not exist when booting over the network.

Several solutions to the problem :

- There is a netboot image of Xubuntu but I don’t know where
- I can trick Xubuntu to fetch `/dev/sr0` on the pxe server. Since it is a device, I don’t know how to do it…
- My pxe configuration misses some options…

Are there articles I can read or keyword I can search for that could help me?

Thanks!

My dnsmasq configuration file :

```
interface=enp1s0,lo
# Only this interface
bind-interfaces
domain=here.local
# DHCP range-leases
dhcp-range=10.0.0.100,10.0.0.199,1h
# PXE
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,10.0.0.254
# Gateway
dhcp-option=3,10.0.0.254
# DNS
dhcp-option=6,10.0.0.254,9.9.9.9
server=9.9.9.9
# Broadcast Address
dhcp-option=28,10.0.0.255
# NTP Server
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0

enable-tftp
tftp-root=/home/me/Desktop/pxe_test/tftproot
```

My pxe file (/home/me/Desktop/pxe_test/tftproot/pxelinux.cfg/default)

```
default menu.c32
prompt 0
menu title Boot Menu
  label localboot
    menu label Boot Local Disk
    localboot 0

  label ubuntu_amd64_18-04-netboot
    menu label Manual Install Ubuntu server 16.04 amd64
    kernel ubuntu_amd64_18-04-netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/linux
    append initrd=ubuntu_amd64_18-04-netboot/ubuntu-installer/amd64/initrd.gz vga=788 

  label xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64
    menu label Manual Install Xubuntu 18.04.1 amd64
    kernel xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/xubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
    append initrd=xubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64/casper/initrd vga=788
```

Answer (score 0):

For start you can refer this nice HowTo:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto

Often it is possible to boot a live CD image - the .iso file - almost directly over PXE but details may differ between versions - try to google something like "boot Ubuntu xx.xx live image over PXE", etc.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.